# Bug? Reputation changes not showing for all members

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Since the start of the Private Beta, I've received upvotes on comments and answers. I've also placed upvotes and downvotes. Still, my profile shows no reputation changes.

I see that other members have plenty of reputation changes registered within the last 12 or so hours.

Can anybody help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've answered one question, and it was here on meta. Votes on site-specific metas have no effect on reputation. Comment upvotes give no reputation.

A recent change has made question down-votes are free. This is true for SO and MSO as well.

For lots of details on what gives reputation, see this meta question: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: So, this is different from other sites on Stack Exchange? I've downvoted a question on the main site. Should that not trigger a reputation decrease?

Comment: @teylyn: Didn't notice that; I've added the explanation to my answer. Try downvoting an answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Also, in the meantime, I've received an upvote on an answer and it reflects in my rep. So this is a free-for-all downvoting spree???? <evil grin> [just joking!]

Comment: @teylyn: If I remember well, downvotes on questions are free but not on answers... I'm not 100% sure though, there was a similar discussion on English EL&U.